# Objective C: View PDF File Link With UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview, nsurlrequest

I am trying to view a PDF file from a server but I only get a view in black and doesn't contain anything. Here's my code:

```
    pdfViewer = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 768, 949)];
    pdfViewer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    pdfViewer.delegate = self;
    [sgContainer addSubview:pdfViewer];

    chatSpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    chatSpinner.frame = CGRectMake(334, 462, 100, 100);
    [pdfViewer addSubview:chatSpinner];

    NSString *httpSource = @"http://www.mywebsite.com/folder/subfolder/file.pdf";
    NSURL *fullUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:httpSource];
    NSURLRequest *httpRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fullUrl];
    [pdfViewer loadRequest:httpRequest];
```

Comment: that link doesn't contain any file

Comment: Run the path in browser and make sure it shows

Comment: @LithuT.V Yes the file that i'll be using is working properly, it can be viewed.

Comment: `sgContainer` is **added to self.view** ?Make sure its outlet is connected if it is from nib or add the `sgContainer` using `addSubview:`

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to display a PDF file residing on a server somewhere, you can simple load it to your web view directly:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

Or if you have a PDF file bundled with your application (in this example named "document.pdf"):

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"document" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

Let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: Your first block of code basically repeats what the OP already has. How does this solve the problem?

Comment: can you recheck your pdf link ?